# How to custom URL in simple blog in Opencart

Tags: opencart-3

I'm use opencart and I use simple blog to write article. After write article and insert SEO keyword. The article showing. but using link `www.myweb.com/my-article` , but my url blog is `www.myweb.com/blog` . How to do for article link like `www.myweb.com/blog/my-article`. Please help me. Thanks